# Copying a sheet to a new workbook in Excel create a error when opening the new file again

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a sub that

- copys a whole sheet to a new workbook
- filters for a specific value in a column
- deletes all rows with other values
- saves the new workbook with a specific path
- closes the new workbook

Actually pretty straight forward but when I open the created file again, I get an error message that says:

> We found a problem with some content in 'FileName.xlsx'.Do you want us
>   to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this
>   workbook, Click Yes

If I click Yes, it opens the file fine and I can save it again and close it. Then the error is gone. But I send that file to partners so I do not want them to get such an error message when opening the file. 
I tried it on different computers, it is always the same.

If I recreate the error in doing all the steps by hand, it appears, that the filtering of the values seems to be the problem. If I filter the values, delete some, delete the filter (show all data again) and then save the file and close it, the error will appear when I re-open the file.

I tried many steps (repair offic, reinstall office etc.) and none of them helped.

Any ideas, what is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

No idea. That's a difficult one to help with. Systematic corruptions errors are unusual but could be caused by a lot things. I had a workbook that would corrupt on every save after copying an image from another workbook.

At least with it being systematic you can comment out all code (except the saving part) and progressively uncomment the code until you identify the exact step causing the issue and then try a different approach to try to resolve the issue.

If all else fails, then after saving the file, you could try to automate the repair process. After saving the file, reopen it, but in the Open method, set CorruptLoad:=xlRepairFile to force a repair on the file and then resave it.

Comment: Thanks!

The crazy thing is, it seems that this is not a VBA problem. It happens when I do the steps by myself too. 
And even crazyer is, that it just happens with one sheet (of the two I would like to export this way). The sheets are basically the same just with a few small differences and I even tried it with removing the differences.

I already did the reopen thing you described. It works with that, but that's just a workaround, not a solution ;) .

Comment: So you've found the exact step that causes the issue?

Comment: Yes. as written above the exact step is the filtering and deleting.
I go: New workbook, copy all used cells from the source workbook (including 6 header rows and one big list object), insert them to the target workbook, then filter to all values but one, delete all those values, remove the filter and save as. 
If i do not filter and delete everything is fine, if I do, it causes the error. Again, on a very similar worksheet it works fine.

Comment: That's still a few steps... filtering, deleting and clearing the filter. Does it still happen if you don't clear the filter afterwards? Does it still happen if you don't delete rows? Also, after it repairs, does it tell you what it repaired at all?

Comment: It happens with the delete. If I just filter, it does not happen. If I filter, delete and save (without clearing the filter) it still happens.
It asks me to repair, then it opens fine without any problems or changes. I then have to save it, close it and then it works normal.

Comment: Do you have any conditional formatting or named ranges overlapping the deleted the rows? Can you try deleting just 1 row manually to reproduce? Can you try deleting just one of the unwanted filter values until reproduced?

Comment: I already thought about names and conditional formatting. I deleted it all and it does not change anything.
But: If I delete the first row, the error appears again, if I just delete the second row it does not happen again. Thanks for that idea!
What else could be different in the first row than in the second?